# NHibernate, one column two meanings, positive/negative

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We have a large management application and we do a lot of logging for every action, for instance, who did what and at what time.

However we have more and more automatic systems which we would like to differentiate as well.

In all of our tables we have a column called PerformedBy which is an int.  This has always been a reference to a Table called Employees which then have a corresponding Name.

However we would now like to have some system users (for instance online payment server, online booking and so on).
We could of cause create these in the employees table however that seems incorrect and we wouldn't be certain of IDs (this is a commercial system, so we have 200 databases which would have to be updated.)

So what I would really like to do is make a mapping so that if an ID is positive it maps to an employee which is loaded from the database.  However, if it is negative I would like to have some static classes which derive from Employee one for each type of system user.

Something like:

```
class OnlineBooking : Employee
{
}
```

Is something like this possible with NHibernate or does someone have another great solution ?
I would like not to add additional columns to ALL the tables that have logs.

Comment: You should really create another column that just says what type the person is... Positive and negative ids... That's a shot in your own foot.

Comment: If you're using relations when auditing I'm guessing you don't allow deleting of any data such as a row in the Employees table otherwise you'll be invalidating a large segment of your audits. I guess you're doing logical deletes or something.

Comment: At the same time how do you cater for changing data, such as an employees name. I have no idea what your system is but in most systems I've passed onto users to use they don't always create new users, they just rename old ones as people leave the company and new users join. Having your name against something you didn't do, instead it was the person before you, isn't that great an audit trail.

Comment: Hi there, why do you think that creating "system users" is wrong? combined with a good RBAC system, it may make a nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One column / two meanings is a classic database smell.    You definitely want to split this into two columns.

You will not be able to enable foreign key constraints with the positive / negative approach that you describe.

http://www.agiledata.org/essays/databaseRefactoringSmells.html

This will also greatly simplify mapping.    Adding a column may seem like a lot of extra work, but it is worth it in the long run.